# Package dependencies can not be resolved error while installing wine in a 64-bit PC

Tags: wine, dependencies

When ever I am trying to install Wine from Ubuntu Software Center, I always get the above said error and details are as follows. Please help me install wine.

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

```
libcheese-gtk23: Depends: cheese-common (= 3.10.2-0ubuntu2) but 3.10.2-0ubuntu2 is to be installed
libcheese7: Depends: libgudev-1.0-0 (>= 146) but 1:204-5ubuntu20.10 is to be installed
        Depends: cheese-common (= 3.10.2-0ubuntu2) but 3.10.2-0ubuntu2 is to be installed
libclutter-1.0-0: Depends: libatk1.0-0 (>= 2.5.3) but 2.10.0-2ubuntu2 is to be installed
              Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14) but 2.19-0ubuntu6.5 is to be installed
              Depends: libfontconfig1 (>= 2.9.0) but 2.11.0-0ubuntu4.1 is to be installed
              Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.37.3) but 2.40.2-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
              Depends: libgtk-3-0 (>= 3.3.18) but 3.10.8-0ubuntu1.4 is to be installed
              Depends: libpango-1.0-0 (>= 1.30) but 1.36.3-1ubuntu1.1 is to be installed
              Depends: libpangocairo-1.0-0 (>= 1.30) but 1.36.3-1ubuntu1.1 is to be installed
              Depends: libpangoft2-1.0-0 (>= 1.30) but 1.36.3-1ubuntu1.1 is to be installed
              Depends: libx11-6 (>= 2:1.2.99.901) but 2:1.6.2-1ubuntu2 is to be installed
              Depends: libxcomposite1 (>= 1:0.3-1) but 1:0.4.4-1 is to be installed
              Depends: libxdamage1 (>= 1:1.1) but 1:1.1.4-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
              Depends: libxi6 (>= 2:1.2.99.4) but 2:1.7.1.901-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
wine1.6: Depends: wine1.6-amd64 (= 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu4) but 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu4 is to be installed
     Depends: wine1.6-i386 (= 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu4) but it is a virtual package
```

Answer (score 0):

To install WINE on your system you can follow these steps:

Open the terminal using Ctrl-Alt-T and use the following command

```
    sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install wine1.6
```

Where `wine1.6` is the current stable version.

> The 1.7 packages are beta packages. This means they will periodically suffer from regressions, and as a result an update may break functionality in Wine. If the stable 1.6 Wine version works for you, then you may not want to use these beta packages.

You can also find more information on:

1. http://www.linux.org/threads/installing-and-configuring-windows-emulator-wine.4368/
2. https://www.winehq.org/download/ubuntu